# Sent email was not received by distribution group

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365, distribution-list

We are using Office 365 Exchange server with Office 2016 Outlook clients. We had an internal user send an email to a distribution group (all internal users). The message seemed to send successfully, but no one in the group received it. I checked message trace in the exchange admin and did not find it. She provided me the message ID and I could not find any results of that in Exchange either. It did not go into spam in our clients and I did not see it in the 365 quarantine. Where could this message have gone or gotten hung?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you reproduce the results.  It's not worth chasing down an edge case, and you'll likely not get an answer anyway.

Is the DG limited as to who can send to it?  If senders are restricted and she is not listed as an approved sender then the message would not go out.  Further if the messages to a DG requrie approval - the message will not be distributed until the approval is granted.

If none of the above are applicable I would say it doesn't sound like the message was actually sent.  If you can replicate the behavior - then open a Microsoft case and have them track it on the back end.  With Sender, Recipient, Subject and time of message they can get some additional information for you.